# Revolution Slider Thumbnail Arrows

Tags: jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have been messing around with every single setting but I cannot seem to get the desired feature.  What I want is to have the thumbnails include arrows so that the user can see a different set of slides from the thumbnail list.  At the moment when the user hovers over the thumbnail list on the slider, it moves in the opposite direction as the mouse so the user can choose different thumbnails.  That's nice, but I want the user to click on arrows attached to the left/right sides of the thumbnail list.

Is this possible?  Do I have to code up something or is there a feature?

Comment: Can you provide some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried any code.  I just wanted to see if the Revolution Slider has any feature that I'm missing first.  I have only tried all the Slider Options for Navigation that come in the package out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this answer is coming too late, but this could be helpful for others if you did not got it already.

Unfortunately there is no option in the settings right now for thumbs arrows. 
but you can add it using java script.

I can not writ full version code here because it may different from situation to anther.

I faced the same issue and I had to write the following code, I used the tabs navigation in the setting then I added my controls and added the events to it.

First you need to add controls to your thumbs could be something like following

```
$(".rev_slider_wrapper").append('<div class="tabs-next tabs-nav"></div>');
$(".rev_slider_wrapper").append('<div class="tabs-prev tabs-nav"></div>');
```

and you would and your style to you navigation buttons .tabs-nav and it could be something else than Divs.

**Avoid to add your controls to .tp-tabs div or any of its children's that is may cause of a conflict in your event and the thumbs animation events.**

Then you could add your event for left & right buttons,
you need to calculate the leftVal as I said this is not full version and you need to adjust it to your code, it is just the basic idea.

```
$(document).on('click', ".tabs-next.tabs-nav", function(event){
    jQuery(".tp-tabs-inner-wrapper").animate({left:   leftVal }, 500, function() { });  
});
$(document).on('click', ".tabs-prev.tabs-nav", function(event){
    jQuery(".tp-tabs-inner-wrapper").animate({left:   leftVal }, 500, function() { });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet out of box via options or settings. The next release v5.0.0 will bring a row of new features and options for navigation.  The next Major release will come in middle of April ! Thanks for your understanding !

Comment: Is it possible to do that in current version ?